# How to force order on X-axis values with Seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, axes

I am plotting the performance of certain models that are loaded from a dataframe. I am doing this using Seaborn. However, the order of the values on the X-axis depends on the order on which one selects the models. For example, in the image below one first selects the model PLD_level_6 and then model PLD_level_5.3:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAULT.png)

As you can see, the values on the X-axis first start with v17 up until v19, and then they start with v13 up until v16. Of course, one would like the values on the X-axis to go in chronological order (i.e. from v13 up until v19). This is indeed the case if one selects the model PLD_level_5.3 first and then the model PLD_level_6, as seen below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwWZc.png)

The reason this happens is because there exists no data for PLD_level_6 w.r.t. v13, v14, v15 and v16. Is there a way to force the fixed order of v13,v14,v15,v16,v17,v18,v19 on the X-axis independent of missing data?

This is the snippet of my code that I use for the plotting:

```
    if (number_of_metrics ==1):
        g = sns.lineplot(x="VERSION", y=metrics1[0], hue="FULL_MODEL_ID", data = v_model_results, ax=axes[0, 0])
        box = g.get_position()
        g.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.85, box.height])
        g.legend(loc='lower right', bbox_to_anchor=(0.8, 1.2), ncol=1)
    if (number_of_metrics > 1):
        g = sns.lineplot(x="VERSION", y=metrics1[0], hue="FULL_MODEL_ID", data = v_model_results, ax=axes[0, 0])
        box = g.get_position()
        g.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.85, box.height])
        g.legend(loc='lower right', bbox_to_anchor=(0.8, 1.5), ncol=1)
        for metric in metrics1[1:]:
            index = metrics1.index(metric)
            sns.lineplot(x="VERSION", y=metric, hue="FULL_MODEL_ID", data = v_model_results, ax=axes[index, 0], legend=False)
        axes[0,0].set_title(f"First set of models: {cell_line1}-{conc1}")
        plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: `v_model_results["VERSION"] = pd.Categorical(v_model_results["VERSION"])` would make them categorical, default sorted lexically.  `v_model_results["VERSION"] = pd.Categorical(v_model_results["VERSION"], ['v13', 'v14', 'v15', 'v16', 'v17', 'v18', 'v19'])` to explicitly set an order.  Seaborn will create an x tick for each.  Note that your question is missing test data and an MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, give your `x` variable a `Categorical` dtype with all categories you want to appear in the order that you desire.

Comment: Could you elaborate in more detail?

Comment: Your question does not offer a reproducible example, so it is difficult to provide specific guidance.